# FBConnect - #import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h" No such file or directory

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode4.2, fbconnect

I am trying to implement Facebook into my application however whenever i go into header search paths and drag and drop my src file i still get an error for "FBConnect/FBConnect.h"
I have already added everything from the fbconnect folder in fcbonnect.xcodeproj without checking the copy into destination group folder.
Please Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to `project->search paths->Header search path`
Add your facebook src directory there.

Comment: Can you post you project directory structure ?

Answer (score 0):

you should to import `Facebook.h` file instead `FBConnect.h`